# Error in android SDK - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3, android-sdk-manager

In my Android SDK I see the error below. What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio

1. Click on Tools from Header Menu.
2. Select Android
3. Select SDK Manager From Dropdown.
4. Reinstall Android Repositary.
5. Restart and Rebuild the project after installation.